# How to reset persistent scrollbar position after div refresh in FF3?

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, scrollbar

I'm experiencing a weird scrollbar issue.  I'm building a page that uses jQuery and PHP to dynamically load images into a DIV sequentially.  This DIV is a fixed height but uses a scrollbar for its variable width.  The problem is that the scrollbar does not reset after a dynamic refresh of the DIV.  So when the user scrolls and then refreshes with new content, the scroll bar position stays persistent instead of resetting back to the left.

This seems to only happen in FF3.  The scrollbar resets perfectly fine in Chrome, Safari, and IE8.

For each refresh, the DIV is hidden, emptied, sized with CSS, then sequentially appended with images.

I've tried resetting `white-space: normal` before the `nowrap`, playing around with `overflow`, and also jQuery's `scrollLeft` to no avail.  It still behaves strangely in FF3, and only FF3.

Click a thumbnail, move the scrollbar then click another thumb.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Wow, that's very strange. My best guess would be to simply grab the element and set it's scrollTop and scrollLeft to zero, this way there should be no fuss. btw, nice site! I love the hash control.

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing ScrollLeft before.  I might revisit that again.  The hashchange plugin is great, eh?.  I should donate some beer money to Ben Alman 'cause it saved me from having to write all that polling stuff!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, after contemplating David M's suggestions, I figured it out.  Since `#interiors` is a child of `#content` it was also being hidden.  So I had to `show` it first, set `scrollLeft` then `hide` it again. A bit kludgy, but whatever works...

```
$('#landing, #interiors, #caption').empty();
$('#content').show()
$('#interiors').scrollLeft(0);
$('#interiors, #caption').hide();
```

Regarding the cached data in FF3, I'm still not clear on that.  Save that one for a rainy day...

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference, here is a relevant Firefox bug:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=706792

Comment: Not just a relevant FF bug - the exact bug which is depicted in this question. +1

Answer (score 0):

When I type this into the firebug interactive console:

```
var e = $('#interiors')[0]
e.scrollLeft = 0
e.scrollTop = 0
```

it seems to reset the scrollbars correctly. The element may also need to be shown with a `display` of `block` before setting `scrollLeft` but I'm not sure - I think that when I tried to do this that Firefox restored the last values when the elements with `overflow: auto` changed from hidden to shown.

**EDIT:** There are a couple of things which you could try to force Firefox to reset the values. First of all, you could remove and then re-add the "content" element when the hash changes:

```
var e = $('#interiors')[0]
var p = e.parentNode
p.removeChild(e)
p.insertBefore(e, p.firstChild) // insert again before the caption
```

Secondly, you could reset the `scrollLeft`/`scrollTop` values to `0` before using `$('#interiors').empty()` or `$('#interiors').hide()` so it doesn't save the values.

Comment: I did more analysing in Firebug. Whats happening is that upon DIV refresh, the scrollLeft value resets to zero until it needs a scrollbar. If the scrollbar is needed, it restores the previous value (you'll see it toggle). If the scrollbar isn't needed the value stays at zero, and subsequent refreshes will use this new stored value of zero whether or not a scrollbar is needed. Now I want to figure out a way to zero or block the old value.

Comment: @rcon: I've added some more suggestions to reset the scrollbar, please reply if you're still having problems

Comment: M: I thought doing a `remove()` would work too, but unfortunately it doesn't. One would think removing an element from the DOM would clear the persistent data. Its a good idea, so I'm going to try playing around with `clone()` next. Regarding the other suggestion, see my reply to Már Örlygsson's answer. Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I edited the javascript to reset the `scrollLeft`/`scrollTop` values before hiding/clearing/setting the HTML. I put all of those operations into a single function to try to figure out what was happening.

I've tested this in Firefox and it seems to fix the scrolling problems, but I haven't tested any other browsers. It should work though.

It seems I was right in my other answer that you need to reset the `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` values in Firefox while the element with an overflow of `auto` is shown with a display of `block` though, as it does seem to restore the old values when shown regardless of whether the scroll values changed while hidden:

```
function setInteriors(html, hide) {
    var i = $('#interiors');

    // Reset the scrollbar positions BEFORE clearing/setting the HTML
    i.scrollLeft(0);
    i.scrollTop(0);

    // Set the HTML if provided, otherwise empty
    if (html) i.html(html);
    else i.empty();

    // Hide the element if hide is `true`
    if (hide) i.hide();
}

function showContent(nav) {
    if($.browser.safari) // webkit browsers
    { 
        bodyelement = $("body")
    }
    else
    { 
        bodyelement = $("html, body")
    }
    bodyelement.animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 300);

    setInteriors(null, true);
    $('#caption').hide();
    $('#caption').empty();
    $('#landing').empty();

    // Detect document window size and use appropriate image heigh images

    if ($(window).height() < 832 ) // size of the document window, not browser window
    {                              // threshold for 600px images + 5 caption lines
        var imageHeight = 500;
    }
    else
    {
        var imageHeight = 600;
    }

    // Show #content so we can show/hide #interiors and #caption individually

    $('#content').show();
    if ((nav == "about") || (nav == "contact"))
    {
        setInteriors(null); // for fast back/forward button mashing

        switch(nav)
        {
            case "about":
                setInteriors($('#hidden-about').html()); // Load from hidden div
                break;
            case "contact":
                setInteriors($('#hidden-contact').html());
                break;
        }
        $('#interiors').css('height', '100%');  // Dimensions for "about" and "contact"
        $('#interiors').css('width', '645px');
        $('#interiors').css('white-space', 'normal');
        $('#interiors').fadeIn(200);
    }
    // TO DO: Maybe separate #interiors to two classes for dynamic changes?
    else
    {
        switch(imageHeight)
        {
            case 500:
                $('#interiors').css('height', '520px');  // Dimensions for gallery
                                                         // Extra 20px for scrollbar
                break;
            case 600:
                $('#interiors').css('height', '620px');
                break;
        }
        $('#interiors').css('width', '100%');
        setInteriors(null); // for fast back/forward button mashing
        $('#interiors').show();
        nav = (location.hash).substring(1); // for fast back/forward button mashing
        $('#caption').html('<P class="caption">' + $('#hidden-' + nav).html() + '</P>'); // load hidden captions
        $('#caption').fadeIn(300);  // show caption before images

        getImages = "http://www.shadowshapes.com/uttwerk/getImages.php?id=" + nav + "&height=" + imageHeight;
        $.getJSON(getImages, function(json) {
            var max = json.length;
            if(max > 0)
            {
                loadImage(0, max, nav);
            }

            function loadImage(index, max, nav) {
                if ((location.hash).substring(1) == nav) // until hash changes, load current nav
                {
                    if(index < max)
                    {
                        var newimg = new Image();
                        $(newimg).load(function () {
                            if ((location.hash).substring(1) == nav) // after current image loads
                            {                                        // continue if no hashchange
                                $('#interiors').append(this);
                                $('#interiors').css('white-space', 'nowrap');
                                $(this).hide();
                                if (max - index > 1)  // add space after each image except last one
                                {
                                    $(this).css('margin-right', '20px');
                                }
                                $(this).css('vertical-align', 'top');
                                $(this).fadeIn(200, function() {
                                        loadImage(index + 1, max, nav);
                                });
                            }
                        }).attr('src', json[index]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

function arrangeStars() {
    $('img.star').each(function () {
        thumbposition = $(this).siblings('a.nav').children('img').position();
        $(this).css("top", (thumbposition.top - 9));
        $(this).css("left", (thumbposition.left - 9));
    });
}

function placeStar(nav) {
    // clear all stars on hash change

    if ($('div.thumb').children('img').hasClass("visiblestar")) {
        $('div.thumb').children('img').removeClass("visiblestar").addClass("hiddenstar");
    }
    // attach star to selected thumbnail

    var test = $('div#_' + nav);
    if ($(test).children('img').hasClass("hiddenstar")) {
        $(test).children('img').removeClass("hiddenstar").addClass("visiblestar");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    //$.imgpreload(['', ''], {each: null, all:null});  

    // bind hover event for empty/contact/about hash only

    $(arrangeStars());  // positions stars in the corner of each thumbnail

    $('img.thumb, img.thumbwithborder').hover(
        function () {  
            var nav = (location.hash).substring(1);
            if ((nav == '') || (nav == "about") || (nav =="contact")) {
                nav = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
                $('div.thumb#' + nav).children('img').removeClass('hiddenstar').addClass('visiblestar');
            }
        },
        function () {  
            var nav = (location.hash).substring(1);
            if ((nav == '') || (nav == "about") || (nav =="contact")) {
                nav = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
                $('div.thumb#' + nav).children('img').removeClass('visiblestar').addClass('hiddenstar');
            }
        }
    );

    // hash change event triggers all the navigation and content switching

    jQuery.hashchangeDelay = 50;

    $(function() { 
        $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
            var nav = (location.hash).substring(1);
            if (nav != '')
            {
                placeStar(nav);
                $('#content').fadeOut(200, function() {
                    showContent(nav);
                });
            }
        });
    })

    if (location.hash != '')
    {
        $(window).trigger('hashchange');
    }

    // load landing content

    $(function() {
        $('#content').hide(function() {
            var landingdiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr({id: 'landing'});
            landingdiv.html($('#hidden-landing').html());
            landingdiv.clone().appendTo('#interiors');
            $(this).fadeIn(200);
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Davin M: Yes, you are absolutely correct. The element should be `display: block`.  Your function works, but only as long as `#content` is not hidden. See my answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same issue and solved it by setting a timeout **AFTER** the `#interiors` has become visible on page.

```
$("#interiors").show(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){$(this).scrollLeft(0);},10);});
});
```